# ImageMagick batch convert all PNGs in subdirectories to JPEGs

Tags: image, batch-file, imagemagick

I have a folder with a number of sub folders in it which contain the images I want to convert from PNG to JPEG.

I have tried:

```
cd d:\images

mogrify -format jpg \*\*.png
```

I tried slashes in both directions (I'm using Windows 7).

But I just get `invalid argument` errors.

What should I do?

I'd really most value a simple example answer rather than a link to a 50 page image ImageMagick documentation if possible (I'm a newbie).

Comment: I'm not at a PC, but try `mogrify -format jpg "*/*.png"`, including the double quotes.

Comment: Thanks, still got invalid argument error :(

Comment: ImageMagick will not traverse subdirectories. You will need to loop over each subdirectory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could always perform a `for`-loop:

```
cd D:\images
for /r /d %%a in (*) do mogrify -format jpg "%%~a\*.png"
```

Which will run the command for every sub-folder such that it is:

```
mogrify -format jpg "D:\images\name of subfolder\*.png"
```

Which appears to meet your requirements.

To use this code in command prompt replace `%%a` with `%a`

#### Edit

To use this code as it is you would need to put it in a batch-file. A very simple procedure for this is to:

1. Open Notepad or any other text editor
2. Copy and paste the code into it
3. Save as and when naming it call it "something.bat"
4. Before clicking save make sure you set the file-type to `All Files (*.*)` in the drop-down menu below the name.
5. Whenever you want to perform the operation simply find "something.bat" or whatever you named it and double click to run.

That way you don't have to open cmd every time you want to perform the action.

Comment: Thanks, not sure if I was meant to subsitute any characters but when I copy and paste it I get "%%a was unexpected at this time".

Comment: if you are using this in command prompt then you use `%a` instead of `%%a`

Comment: Thanks! it works. What would I have to add in to set the jpg quality to say 95%?

Comment: All you have to do is modify the `mogrify -format jpg "%%~a\*.png"` part of the code. I don't use it myself so I can't help you to much but as a general pointer every command line tool I know (or use) will provide a help option. Type `mogrify -?` or `mogrify -help` and there should be a very succinct explanation on how to use the tool

Comment: Ok thanks I should be able to work it out, anyway 85% default is probably ok. The first example with two %% that wasn't suitable for command prompt, when would you need to use that?

Answer (score 12):

Try using the following at the cmd prompt:

```
mogrify -format jpg *.png
```

I wasted hours trying use the [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) convert command in a batch file, but couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

> **For novice:**

Download ImageMagick from below link:

https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php

then just copy and paste below command in cmd:

```
for /r /d %a in (*) do "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.6-Q16\magick.exe" mogrify -format png "%~a\*.jpg"
```

The above command is working fine for me which converts all files from JPGs to PNGs, present in the current directory.

And then if you want to remove all the residual JPGs, just hit the below command:

```
for /r %i in (*.jpg) do del "%i"
```

Answer (score 1):

**ImageMagick mogrify will not traverse directories**. You will have to write a script loop over each directory that you want. Then in the loop change directories and run mogrify -format jpg *.png for each directory. I also recommend that you either backup your directories or use -path to set a path to your new but empty output directories.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have *Imagemagick* installed, just *IrfanView*.

One *IrfanView* solution would be for example:

```
@echo off
for /R "D:\images" %%F in (*.png) do (
    "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IrfanView\i_view32.exe "%%~F" /convert "%%~dpnF.jpg"
)
```

Another, faster IrfanView solution would be:

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\images"
for /R %%F in (.) do (
    "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "%%~fF\*.png" /convert "%%~fF\*.jpg"
)
popd
```

Use the second example with replacing the *IrfanView* command with the *mogrify* command:

```
@echo off
pushd "D:\images"
for /R %%F in (.) do (
    "Path to mogrify\mogrify.exe" -format jpg "%%~fF\*.png"
)
popd
```

To understand the commands **for**, **pushd** and **popd** as well as `%%~F`, `%%~dpnF` and `%%~fF` open a command prompt window, execute the following commands, and read output help for each command.

- `for /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `popd /?`

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at irfanview as well.

Answer (score -1):

A solution using Python to traverse the subdirectories:

```
import glob,os
paths = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for name in files:
        if ".png" in name:
            paths.append(os.path.join(path, name))

for p in paths:
    cmd = "convert " + p + " " + p[:-4] + ".jpg"
    os.system(cmd)
    os.system("rm " + p)
```